# qtp object repository not working

Tags: qtp

Here is problem :

Recording working fine and record all the object and running few object and not runing few object. When i am going to object repository to see whether object is saved in it or not. QTP recoginizing some object in application and some not..

So i am trying to using Object Spy recoginizing that object(which is not understand by qtp) and using highlity i am make sure that qtp understand and then add that object to repository perfectly, now repository should recognize this problem but it is not recognizing that object.

so problem conclusiong, reocrding is record object perfectly and object spy also recognizing perfectly but object repository is not recognizing

QTP VERSION 11
QTP POWER BULIDER IS 12.5
POWER BULIDER VERSION IS 12

What i did here to correct problem:

Repair qtp but problem is not sloved.

QTP 11 OBJECT REPOSITORY ISSUE.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Enable Smart Identification on? Sometimes I run into problems where an object would be identified using object spy but sporadically during run time qtp would complain it can't find the object in the particular page.

If that doesn't work, try using a different object property to identify the object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Something that may seem obvious to do, but is often overlooked, is to start with a very basic set of properties and confirm that QTP/ObjectSpy/Object Repository can see the object, then narrow down the query further.  If you have multiple objects that are visible, you may want to set an index if you are doing descriptive identification programming and can figure out which is which.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add some properties to identify the object. Try to add HTML id as it will be unique always. Smart identification can create problem if it is on, turn smart identification off and give it a go.